# DiscordJS Check if command user has a role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have managed to do this before, however it is now not working when making a new command, despite it working with the other.

I am trying to check if the command user has a role, and then they will execute the command differently if they do. I am doing the following

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.filter(role => role.name == "Castaways").size == 1) {

console.log("Works")

}
```

I managed to find something which helped change the error. I did npm update, and now message.member is now defined. I can see message.member.roles however, it is now stating that message.member.roles.cache is undefined.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

Some help to where I may be going wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RoleManager#has()` if you have the id (Recommended)

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.has('role-id-here')) {
   // Member has that role!
}
```

Or `RoleManager#some()` if you want to look for the role by it's name.

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === 'Castaways')) {
   // Member has that role!
}
```

[View the official documentation for Permissions](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#roles-as-bot-permissions)

Make sure your DJS version is atleast v12, as this is the version where `.cache` is introduced.

Comment: Thanks so much, i probably should do role. Will do in future. Updated my discord.js which it now works. Didnt realise different projects could be running different versions of discord.js so easily. thank you.

Comment: For people who need to update their DJS. Change the discord version in the package.json , then run npm install discord.js.
You can also see what verion of DJS you have installed by using npm list discord.js