# How can I check if user has a role?

Tags: discord.js

I can't seem to get the bot to check if the user has the roles, I've tried for an hour and I couldn't figure it out.

```js
let modrole = message.author.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === db.get("modrole_${message.guild.id}"));
```

The `db.get("modrole_${message.guild.id}")` returns the role id.

```js
if(message.member.roles.cache.has(modrole)) {
 message.reply("Member With Role!");
}
```

Error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DiscordJS Check if command user has a role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037110/discordjs-check-if-command-user-has-a-role) - Notice they use the role *id* rather than the role object. Also remember to use `message.member`, **not** `message.author`

Comment: still not working. I've tried it and it shows me **TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined** once more.

Comment: Instead of `message.author.guild` use `message.guild`

Comment: `"modrole_${message.guild.id}"` is not a valid template string, use backtics instead of double quotes

Comment: i know, I had to use **""** because it wouldn't let me post my question.

Answer (score 0):

`message.author` represents a Discord user, which doesn't have a guild specifically assigned, unlike a `message`. The following code without the message author queried, should work.

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.find(/*role id*/);
```